# Select one recent row for that record with group by two columns

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select the newest record ordering by `RequestDate` if that has the `RoomStatus` as `Request` having the same id `RoomId` and `RequesterId`.

I have writtien the following query but this doesn't help to produce the output infact this is giving me the error:

```
var query = _dbContext.RoomReservation
                  .Include(x => x.Room)
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.RoomId, x.RequesterId })
                  .Select(room => new
                  {
                      Status = room.First().Status,
                      RoomId = room.First().BookId,
                      Name = room.First().Room.Name
                  }).Where(x => x.Status == Domain.Roomtatus.Requested);
```

Error i am getting is:

> .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
> ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I mean to group by `RoomId`, `RequesterId`, order each key's item list by `RequestDate` descending, and pick the first.

**Included Class:**

```
public class RoomReservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RoomStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RequesterId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

What is the correct way of Group By with multiple columns with an order by? What I am missing in my Linq query?

Comment: Don't forget that call to method GroupBy here most likely returns `IGrouping<{ x.RoomId, x.RequesterId }, IEnumerable<RoomReservation>>` so it should be `room.First().Room.Status` or smth like that. Anyway the problem might be that all of this cannot be properly translated to SQL query in which case this needs to be broken down to a few separate queries.

Comment: Have you tried using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`? I think I remember something about certain EF versions only allowing `First` at the end and not inside the query. The problem seems to be that `First` will throw an exception if there is no first, this throwing behaviour cannot be translated to SQL. If you replace with `FirstOrDefault` it won't throw an exception anymore and it becomes possible to translate it to SQL.

Comment: Got the same error with `FirstOrDefault` as well.

Comment: It is not possible with EF in effective way. I suggest to write SQL with ROWN_NUMBER usage. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108543/10646316

Comment: I do not think anyone can help you. Enter RoomReservation class codes and included classes to simulate the same query

Comment: @meysamasadi, why you think so? ;) I know even why this query is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and it worked without any problems. See the data is accurate

```
var query = _dbContext.RoomReservations.OrderBy(a => a.RequestDate)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.RoomId, x.RequesterId })
.Select(room => new
{
   Status = (Int16)room.FirstOrDefault().Status,
   RoomId = room.FirstOrDefault().RoomId,
   Name = room.FirstOrDefault().Room.Name
}).Where(x => x.Status == (int)RoomStatus.Requested).ToList();
```

**or try this**

```
var query = _dbContext.RoomReservations.GroupBy(p => new { p.RoomId, p.RequesterId })
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.RequestDate).FirstOrDefault())
        .Select(room => new
        {
           Status = room.Status,
           RoomId = room.RoomId,
           Name= room.Room.Name
        }).ToList();
```

**sql query**

```
 WITH summery AS (
   SELECT p.Status, 
           p.RoomId,
           p.RequestDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC) AS rk
FROM RoomReservation p
RIGHT JOIN(
  SELECT RoomId, RequesterId
  FROM   RoomReservation
  group by RoomId, RequesterId
) A
ON A.RoomId = p.RoomId)

SELECT *
  FROM summery
  inner join Room on summery.RoomId = Room.Id
where summery.Status = 1 and summery.rk = 1
order by summery.RoomId
```

**sql data**

[image]

**with GroupBy(x => new { x.RoomId, x.RequesterId })**

[image]

**with GroupBy(x => new { x.RequesterId })**

[image]

**sql output**
[image]

Comment: I want to include the order by with the date as well

Comment: Well, enter the order table as well

Comment: `OrderBy` RequestDate.

Comment: And also you are using the `List<RoomReservation>`, I am using the Entity Framework and extracting the data from the database. Do you think will it be the same?

Comment: I also simulate it with entity

Comment: It is not LINQ to Entites. it is `IEnumerablle` extensions. It has nothing with SQL.

Comment: I modified the code. This code reads information from the database through the entity framework. Tell me if you would like me to send the test data as well

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv So where is the source of information if it is not sql

Comment: @meysamasadi. You have changed original message. BUT show me generated SQL if you think this query will work. I have stable crash even on simpler  LINQ query.

Comment: @meysamasadi, No SQL, only images? Which EF do you use? If it is EF6, you will be surprised  that whole table were loaded into the memory. SQL is prove that your LINQ query is ok.

Comment: I entered the SQL query, I think the display order should be changed. It's a simple matter

Comment: I am using EF Core in ASP.net core 3.1 application, but this code still doesn't work.

Comment: @meysamasadi, this is not EF query. EF 6 has weird formatting. And please paste query, not images.

Comment: At least SQL is almost ok. +1

Comment: I put another code. Test it, I think it works.
I entered the SQL query. if linq not work Use the Stored Procedure