# How to make a GroupBy call on the server side EF Core 3

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, entity-framework-core, server-side

Way too many questions were asked on this topic and of course I've tried to clarify my misunderstanding, googling existing answers, but it seems like I need a bit more details.

As it turned out for me, before EF Core 2 `GroupBy` was executing on the client side, want you that or not. But in EF 3 Core that behavior had been changed and now you have to execute it on the client **explicitly**, by calling `ToList` or something else and then using `IEnumerable`'s `GroupBy`. So with this approach we always know the risks of probable big memory allocations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

But I want to execute `GroupBy` on the server side. That's the thing. So what do I have to do? Create a procedure? Also I'm interested why wasn't it executing on the server side at the very beginning?

My case is very simple: I want to get records of some groups with the maximum column value. Like that guy on the screenshot tried to do that, but on the server level.

[image]

Comment: If you know SQL, it is invalid query for Database Server. Eg. After GroupBy you can get ONLY grouping keys and aggregation results. In your case you are trying to get WHOLE record. Maybe you may this my answer useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108028/how-to-get-the-last-messages-among-users-with-linq/64108543#64108543

Comment: *big memory allocations* Why? Group by with only aggregated data is supported. If you want full records in groups you're going to pull all the data from the database anyway. The only thing is: as off EF-core 3 you have to do the grouping yourself. Don't ask us why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I came to is:

```
var query = _dbContext.ReportVersions
    .Select(version => version.VersionGroupId).Distinct()
    .SelectMany(key => _dbContext.Reports.Where(report => report.ReportVersion.VersionGroupId == key)
        .OrderByDescending(report => report.ReportVersion.CreatedAt)
        .Select(report => new
        {
            Id = report.Id,
           // etc
        })
        .Take(1))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

It reminds `group by`, as you can see firstly I'm looking for unique values (VersionGroupId), after that I'm looking for reports, which have that VersionGroupId, and order them. Now I've got all records in the "group" and I'm taking top one of each.

It's done with a subquery, but with this approach you don't load unwanted entities in memory.

Comment: This answer is a hidden GEM of stackoverflow. Thank you, everything else doesn't work.